# Connecting UIViewControllers with a image using touchesBegan

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I got a MainViewController who has addes a SubViewController.

In the SubViewController there another SubSubViewController who has image inside witch will be clicked sometimes.

When touchesBegan dispatch the delegate of SubSubViewController is getting called.

Now i need this.

[mainViewController method] inside the SubSubViewController. How do i connect to this parent?

Any help would be really nice!!

Michiel

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use your AppDelegate.

```
[ (AppDelegate*)[ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] delegate ] doSomething ];
```

Good Luck !
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

You could do: `[[subsubView superview] superview]` to get a reference to your mainview. Or you could use a subclass for your subsubview and give it a property and set it to keep a reference to its super-viewcontroller upon creation.

Edit: Forget about superview, it works only for views, you're interested in viewcontrollers. Sorry I got you wrong. Try keeping a reference, besides using a property in the VC itself, you could store it in the appdelegate or another singleton to make it easy to access.